# MapFragment on a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Im developing an app that displays a map on a fragment. Everything is set up, but there's small thing that is not letting me finish it.

**gMapFragment.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class gMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    public gMapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng marker = new LatLng(46.33328, 15.38173);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker,13));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(("HERE WE ARE!")).position(marker));

    }
}
```

I call this fragment from button in another frament and this is the method that calls it:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.SearchButton:
            fragment = new gMapFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
            break;
    }
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I get error "*gMapFragment cannot be converted to fragment*" Any idea how to fix this? thanks!

Comment: the second code block is inside a Fragment?  Better to put the FragmentTransaction code in the Activity.....

Comment: Yes, is inside a fragment. I cant put into activity....

Comment: Yes, you can, just define a public method in the Activity that does a FragmentTransaction to replace the current Fragment with the Google Map Fragment, and call that method from your onClicke() method in the Fragment.

Comment: OK, i´ll try that. But i dont think that´s the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that you're consistent with your Fragment imports.  Use either `import android.app.Fragment` in all classes or  `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in all classes.  Don't mix-and-match.

Then, add this to the Activity:

```
public void openMapFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = new gMapFragment();
    replaceFragment(fragment);
}

//moved to Activity from the Fragment
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Then, in the Fragment `onClick()` method, just call into the Activity to do the FragmentTransaction:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.SearchButton:
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.openMapFragment();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it works. But i had to make sure i have `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of the other one, otherwise it wouldnt work